# Reverse skew transform on svg line

Tags: css, svg, css-transforms

I'm trying to apply a skewX transform on a vertical line but it looks like no matter how i set y1 and y2 the skew angle will always start from "above" coord. Is there any way to control this tilt angle, i.e. make it start from "below"?

```css
svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

line {
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 3;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <line x1="200" y1="200" x2="200" y2="100" style="transform: skewX(7deg);"></line>
</svg>
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) ...?

Comment: not sure how that will help

Comment: Not sure I understand what you actually mean then.

Comment: basically i want to control the skew angle starting point, as i mentioned, it appears to always start from top

Comment: Add a second line to your SVG that does not get transformed, and then apply `transform-origin: 50% 100%;` to the first one via browser dev tools, and change the second value, 100%, to something more, or less - see how the line moves now, in regard to the static "clone"? If that is _not_ what you are asking for - then you really need to give a better explanation, of what actually is.

Comment: What is the goal in the first place? For a line it would make more sense to use rotate().

Comment: goal is to give a tilt to vertical (overlapping) lines from css so you can distinguish them on hover AND to be able to define the source of slope

Answer (score 1):

The origin is really important here. As a starting point (no point intended) the origin is in 0,0. So, then you compare a line that is skewed with one that is not it looks strange:

```css
svg {
    border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" stroke-width="10">
  <line x1="200" y1="200" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="red" transform="skewX(7)"/>
  <line x1="200" y1="200" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="green"/>
</svg>
```

If you let both lines start at 0,0 (the origin) you can see that they overlap in the top. It makes more sense than the first example.

```css
svg {
    border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" stroke-width="10">
  <g transform="translate(200 100)">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100" stroke="red" transform="skewX(7)"/>
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100" stroke="green"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

With that knowledge it is easier to see that you need to move the origin. And now read the following transform attribute (`transform="translate(0 100) skewX(7) translate(0 -100)"`) from behind: Move the origin to the bottom of the line, skew it and then move the line back again.

```css
svg {
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" stroke-width="10">
  <g transform="translate(200 100)">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100" stroke="red"
      transform="translate(0 100) skewX(7) translate(0 -100)"/>
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100" stroke="green"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```